# left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer when trying to round variable and use operator

Tags: c#, indexer, math.round

Code is returning: *"The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer"*

I'm still new to C# (coming from python), but I understand this issue, however I've got no clue how to fix it

I essentially want to have `input` initially equal `x` round `x` each cycle and multiply that rounded number by input y:

```
Console.WriteLine ("input x:");
int inputx = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine ("input y:");
double y = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

double input = inputx;

for (int i = 0, i < a, i++)
    Math.Round(input) *= y;

Console.WriteLine ("Value output: {0}", input);
```

Comment: `input = Math.Round(input) * y`

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from the line in the loop. What it's trying to do is to multiply `Math.Round(input)` and `y`, and then assign the result to `Math.Round(input)` which isn't a variable, it's and expression.

To get it to work you'll have to separate the multiplication and the assignment, instead using the following line.

```cs
input = Math.Round(input) * y;
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it not just be this?

```
input = Math.Round(input) * y;
```

Comment: Hahaha, beaten by 44 seconds...